# Is there a way to achieve `as` semantics combined with generics?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a generic string to number function in Rust where the supported types are `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `u32`, `u64`, `f32` and `f64`.
Initially I had this:

```
fn str_to_num<N>(s: &str, default_res: N) -> N
where
    N: FromStr,
{
    if let Ok(n) = N::from_str(s) {
        return n;
    }
    default_res
}
```

And this worked fine until I was asked to support also hex strings.
Since we only want to parse hex string as integers, I now have 2 versions of the function:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn str_to_num_with_hex<N>(s: &str, default_res: N) -> N
where
    N: FromStr + TryFrom<u64>,
{
    if s.starts_with("0x") || s.starts_with("0X") {
        if let Ok(n) = u64::from_str_radix(&s[2..], 16) {
            if let Ok(n) = N::try_from(n) {
                return n;
            }
        }
    }
    return str_to_num(s, default_res);
}

fn str_to_num<N>(s: &str, default_res: N) -> N
where
    N: FromStr,
{
    if let Ok(n) = N::from_str(s) {
        return n;
    }
    default_res
}
```

However when testing the function with an hex string which fits into `u64` but not into `i64`, it seems that `TryFrom` and `as` behave differently. Is there a way to achieve `as` semantics combined with generics?

```
fn main() {
    let hex = "0xB85991EE5DA2B557";
    let unsigned_long: u64 = str_to_num_with_hex(hex, 0);
    let signed_long: i64 = str_to_num_with_hex(hex, 0);
    println!("{}", unsigned_long); // prints 13283809028865176919
    println!("{}", signed_long); // prints 0
    println!("{}", unsigned_long as i64); // prints -5162935044844374697
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. `as` literally can not fail, and sadly, for convenience and in keeping with existing languages Rust decided to implement `as` for potentially lossy numeric conversions e.g. `isize as u8`.

`try_from` can actually fail, that's the entire point. So if faced with a lossy conversion (input out of range), it'll fail, that's pretty much the point.

I'd suggest creating your own trait for the semantics you desire e.g.

```rust
trait FromHex where Self: Sized {
    fn from_hex(s: &str) -> Option<Self>;
}

impl FromHex for u64 {
    fn from_hex(s: &str) -> Option<u64> {
        u64::from_str_radix(s, 16).ok()
    }
}
impl FromHex for i64 {
    fn from_hex(s: &str) -> Option<i64> {
        u64::from_hex(s).map(|v| v as i64)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "B85991EE5DA2B557";
    println!("{:?} {:?}", u64::from_hex(s), i64::from_hex(s));
}
```

[conv](https://docs.rs/conv/) might also do what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`num::cast::AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) trait if you want exactly the same semantics as `as`:

```rust
use num::cast::AsPrimitive; // 0.3.1
use std::str::FromStr;

fn str_to_num_with_hex<N>(s: &str, default_res: N) -> N
where
    N: FromStr + Copy + 'static,
    u64: AsPrimitive<N>,
{
    from_hex(s)
        .or_else(|| N::from_str(s).ok())
        .unwrap_or(default_res)
}

fn from_hex<N>(s: &str) -> Option<N>
where
    N: Copy + 'static,
    u64: AsPrimitive<N>,
{
    let v = s.strip_prefix("0x").or_else(|| s.strip_prefix("0X"))?;
    let n = u64::from_str_radix(v, 16).ok()?;
    Some(n.as_())
}

fn main() {
    let hex = "0xB85991EE5DA2B557";
    let unsigned_long: u64 = str_to_num_with_hex(hex, 0);
    let signed_long: i64 = str_to_num_with_hex(hex, 0);
    println!("{}", unsigned_long); 
    println!("{}", signed_long); 
    println!("{}", unsigned_long as i64);
}
```

```
13283809028865176919
-5162935044844374697
-5162935044844374697
```